# How to set subreports pagination in SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

let say I have a report called Project list. 
If I run project list report, I get 6 pages (per page is set as 8.5x11)

then I have a Master Report. Let say inside master report I have 3 sub reports

1. Sales report
2. Finance report
3. and Project list

I want to be able to run Master report and only get 3 pages.

1. page 1 is sales report
2. page 2 is Finance reports
3. and page 3 is project list

how can I do this in SSRS 2012 RTM?

Thank you

Edit 1: when I mention

1. page 1 is sales report
2. page 2 is Finance reports
3. and page 3 is project list

I meant one page in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up to make both master report and Project list report to be one long scroll in IE

The way I do it is to set interactive size length = 0

this solved the problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the sub report is 6 pages long then if your master report is at lease 6 times the size you may be able to get it to work, otherwise there is no way if you have it as a sub report to make the master report smaller that I know of.

If the master report just supposed to be a summary of the Project List report, then you can just have the same data set of the sub report and have page 3 have a table linked to that data set where you group the data onto one page.

Comment: What I meant is in browser IE , the report should only be 1 page. I know I can set the interactive size height to 0 and that will keep it one long scroll in IE. But I want this only on the master report. but keep the report it self as is.. is it possible?